# MALFORMED_DATE Error During Import with Mixed Date Formats in QuickSight

Tags: data-analysis, amazon-quicksight

Hello QuickSight Community,

I am encountering an issue during data import in QuickSight, specifically a MALFORMED_DATE error that results in skipping rows. The data column in question contains date values, but they are formatted inconsistently, leading to this error. The formats present in my data are "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ" and "MM-dd-yyyy".

Issue Details:

Error Encountered: MALFORMED_DATE - This error occurs during the data import process, causing certain rows to be skipped.
Data Format: The date column in my dataset contains two different date formats:
ISO 8601 Format: "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ"
US Format: "MM-dd-yyyy"
Possible Cause: I suspect the error is due to the presence of these two different date formats, as QuickSight might be expecting a single, consistent format for date fields.

Steps Taken:

I have checked for non-date values and ensured there are no column headers mixed into the data.
I attempted to standardize the date format in the source file, but due to the nature of the data collection, this isn't always feasible.
Request for Assistance:

Is there a way to configure QuickSight to handle multiple date formats within the same column during import?
Are there any recommended workarounds or settings adjustments that could resolve this issue?
Any insights, suggestions, or guidance from the community would be greatly appreciated. If further information is required, I am happy to provide it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!